# Caption position in LaTeX

Tags: pdftex, captions, miktex

I have a figure in which i have labelled axes manually.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
 \centering
\setlength{\unitlength}{0.1\textwidth}
\begin{picture}(5,3.5)

 \put(-0.1,0.1){$0$}
  \put(-0.1,3){$1$}
 \put(-1.0,1.55){$S(T)$}
  \put(0.13,-0.2){$0$}
   \put(4.90,-0.2){$T$}

 \put(2.5,-0.5){$t$}
 \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=0.50\textwidth]{switchmod.eps}}
\end{picture}
\caption{Switch model}
 \label{fig:lion}
\end{figure}
```

And the output is 
[image]

As clear from picture, figure caption and my manual labeling have been overlapped. How to create space such that caption is much lower?

Comment: Adjust the `picture`s size and offset. `(5,3.5)` in your code now.

Comment: Or consider using the `tikz` package instead of the `picture` env. Then the sizes are automatically adjusted.

Comment: @Paul adjusting picture size and offset did not help as it was dealing picture as a whole. Means shifting the whole picture with labels up , down or left, right. I need to the option such that caption is much lower. How to specify the position?

Comment: You can use the second `()` optional argunment of `picture` to allow for your negative coordinates, but simpler is just leave a blank line after the picture and put `\vspace{5cm}` before the caption

Comment: used    \vspace{5cm} . It worked. Thank you

Comment: Is placing the caption *above* rather than below the graphic an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the second `()` optional argument of `picture` to allow for your negative coordinates, but simpler is just leave a blank line after the picture and put

```
\vspace{5cm}
```

before the caption